# Google Places API : Is the option to switch off location biasing been removed from auto complete API?

Tags: autocomplete, location, google-places-api

Previously there was an option to disable location biasing by passing location=0,0 & radius=20000000, now this option is no longer available on the API docs. There is also change in the results of autocomplete API with location=0,0 & radius=20000000.

Answer (score 2):

I had success turning off biasing by using location=0,0 and radius=1.

location=0,0 and radius=20000000 seemed to have the effect of biasing *everything*. That configuration resulted in some odd results like searching for "belize" and being returned only cities and provinces in Belize and not the country of Belize.

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed this and it behaves strange. For eg: when you search with input text "New" and location=0,0&radius=20000000, you will get 
"New No. 142, Velachery Road, Next To Raptakos Brett & Co, opp. Maruthi Driving School, Indira Gandhi Nagar, Velachery, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India". This is not at all justifiable when there are many other popular cities like New York is present in the bottom of the autocomplete list. An answer on this is appreciated.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=New&key=&location=0,0&radius=20000000

Created a ticket with google support and waiting for their answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Did you get an answer from google support?

Comment: Can you link that support ticket or give us the response? I'd like to not open my own ticket if possible! Thanks!!